# knockout sorting not working

Tags: javascript, sorting, knockout.js

I am trying to sort my grid. Below is my code

```
ko.moveInGrid = {
    // Defines a view model class you can use to populate a grid
    viewModel : function(configuration) {
        this.data = configuration.data;
        this.currentPageIndex = ko.observable(0);
        this.pageSize = configuration.pageSize || 5;

        // If you don't specify columns configuration, we'll use scaffolding
        this.columns = configuration.columns
                || getColumnsForScaffolding(ko.utils
                        .unwrapObservable(this.data));
        this.actions = configuration.actions;

        this.itemsOnCurrentPage = ko.computed(function() {
            var startIndex = this.pageSize * this.currentPageIndex();
            return this.data.slice(startIndex, startIndex + this.pageSize);
        }, this);

        this.maxPageIndex = ko.computed(function() {
            return Math.ceil(ko.utils.unwrapObservable(this.data).length
                    / this.pageSize) - 1;
        }, this);
         this.sortByName = function() {
             console.info(configuration.columns);
             console.log("this works");
             configuration.sort(function(a, b) {
                    return a.name < b.name ? -1 : 1;
                });
            };
    }
};
```

And this is how I am calling my `function`

```
<th data-bind=\"click: $root.sortByName,attr:{'data-translate': headerText}\" class=\"sorting\"></th>\
```

My `ViewModel` is fine. When I click on my header, it says the following error

```
TypeError: configuration.sort is not a function
```

Comment: configuration object is missing sort function?

Comment: yes I have checked `configuration.data.sort()` it does not throw any error but sorting simply doesn't work

Comment: Inface `configuaration.data` contains `sort()` function

Comment: but you are using configuration.sort not configuration.data.sort in above code

Comment: well I tried with configuration.data.sort and changed `configuration.sort(function(a, b) {
                    return a.name < b.name ? -1 : 1;
                });` to `configuration.sort(function(a, b) {

                    return a.name > b.name ? -1 : 1;
                });` with if conditions, it worked for me

Answer (score 0):

I saw you want to sort name,
I guest that name is in viewModel.data. So you can first test below code its work

```
viewModel.data.sort(function(a, b) {
                return a.name < b.name ? -1 : 1;
            });).
```